# Creating bumpy glass effect on an extruded path?

Tags: glass, svg, bump

I want to make a glass material with specific bump pattern on an SVG image that I've extruded and converted to mesh.I've been using bump node and connected its normal output to the normal input of glass node but that doesn't affect the final render.
I'm using blender 2.81 with Eevee engine.
[image: shading node structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you must add a B&W conversion node between Bump and the Texture node as Bump node requires a greyscale image to work.